# Simple but reasonably accurate algorithm to determine if tag / keyword is related to an image

Tags: image, algorithm, tags, keyword, training-data

I have a hard problem to solve which is about automatic image keywording. You can assume that I have a database with 100000+ keyworded low quality jpeg images for training (low quality = low resolution about 300x300px + low compression ratio). Each image has about 40 mostly accurate keywords (data may contain slight "noise"). I can also extract some data on keyword correlations.

Given a color image and a keyword, I want to determine the probability that the keyword is related to this image.

I need a creative understandable solution which I could implement on my own in about a month or less (I plan to use python). What I found so far is machine learning, neural networks and genetic algorithms. I was also thinking about generating some kind of signatures for each keyword which I could then use to check against not yet seen images.

Crazy/novel ideas are appreciated as well if they are practicable. I'm also open to using other python libraries.

My current algorithm is extremely complex and computationally heavy. It suggests keywords instead of calculating probability and 50% of suggested keywords are not accurate.

Comment: You're asking for an algorithm capable of *semantically parsing* an image - more or less, the Holy Grail of Computer Vision. Can you limit somewhat the field? Is there a single 'topic', or a few, for the photos in question?

Comment: The photos can be anything really. Right now they are mostly abstract images. From clouds to complex patterns, usually no people or text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the hard requirements of the application, only gross and brainless solutions can be proposed.

For every image, use some segmentation method and keep, say, the four largest segments. Distinguish one or two of them as being background (those extending to the image borders), and the others as foreground, or item of interest.

Characterize the segments in terms of dominant color (using a very rough classification based on color primaries), and in terms of shape (size relative to the image, circularity, number of holes, dominant orientation and a few others).

Then for every keyword you can build a classifier that decides if a given image has/hasn't this keyword. After training, the classifiers will tell you if the image has/hasn't the keyword(s). If you use a fuzzy classification, you get a "probability".

Comment: That's actually not bad and it sounds doable, especially if I can find some libraries ready to use. Disassemble image into distinct areas, assign multiple metrics to each one and somehow determine the class based on patterns in those metrics. Can you suggest a good classifier algorithm?

Comment: Sounds like what I would need and it seems well documented. Thanks, I'll accept your answer :)